# How do I get the href to format properly in the responsive class?

Tags: css, href

I know I'm missing something simple, but working on a responsive email and cannot get the links to format properly with css

I've tried creating a class and assigning it, the same thing. Tried spans etc.  I've never been too bright with CSS.  Thanks.

I have been at it for a little bit trying different types that I could find and am probably just going a little crazy since I don't primarily code and I'm working on a responsive email layout.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

    <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        #templateColumns{
            width:100% !important;
        }


        .templateColumnContainer{
            display:block !important;
            width:100% !important;
        }

        .columnImage{
            height:auto !important;
            max-width:480px !important;
            width:100% !important;
        }

        .leftColumnContent{
            font-size:16px !important;
            line-height:125% !important;

        }

        .rightColumnContent{
            font-size:16px !important;
            line-height:125% !important;

        }

         .rightColumnContent  .leftColumnContent a {
            font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;

        }
        img.header {
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
            }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" id="templateColumns">

    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer"><!-- Deal 1-->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumnContent">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=adorable-animal-cat-20787.jpg&fm=jpg"  width="380" style="max-width:380px;" class="columnImage" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="leftColumnContent">
                         <a href="#">Sengled Pulse LED Smart Bulb with JBL Bluetooth Speaker (2-Pack)</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer"><!-- Deal 2 -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="rightColumnContent">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=adorable-animal-cat-20787.jpg&fm=jpg" width="380" style="max-width:380px;" class="columnImage" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="rightColumnContent">
                        <a href="#" >Apple iPad 3 Retina Bundle with Case and Screen Protector (32GB)</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take care with your tags. You have two closing head tags, so your style is not in the head. You also have an extra opening body tag at the end of your html (before the closing one), so your body is not being closed properly. Also, you can remove all the !important s from your style

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a rule that looks like:

```
a {
 color: preferred-link-color;
}
```

This will affect all `<a>` elements in your document.

And since it's an email you may want to inline the styles to boot! I believe gmail/Android clients strip out `<style>` tags. There are services for this, so you can do it efficiently.